# What Discount property means in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

GA 4 has few events that have **discount** property. From the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/ga4-events#purchase

> Discount - Monetary value of discount associated with a purchase.

But how it works with **Price** / **Value** properties?

I want to log that I sold a product costing 1000 EUR with 10% discount. Should I report Discount 100, Price & Value 1000? Or maybe Price/Value should be 1100 and then Discount 100?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Purchasing a $1,000 product with a 10% discount should be tracked as a $900 price & $100 discount:

```json
{
    value: 900,
    items: [{
        price: 900,
        discount: 100,
        quantity: 1
    }]
}
```

and purchasing two would be tracked as:

```json
{
    value: 1800,
    items: [{
        price: 900,
        discount: 100,
        quantity: 2
    }]
}
```

## Explanation

It looks like the GA4 documentation & examples provide some contradictory information.

[GA4 > Recommended Events > purchase](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#purchase) example shows that the `ecommerce.value` would be calculated as the sum of the ecommerce.items[] `(price - discount) * quantity`

However, their [Apply a discount to an ecommerce event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/apply-discount?hl=en&client_type=gtm) article shows that the `ecommerce.value` would be calculated as the sum of the ecommerce.items[] `price * quantity`.

Google Analytics use the ecommerce.item's price & quantity to determine "Item Revenue" metric on Ecommerce Reports. The [Ecommerce purchases report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12924131), calculates the "Item revenue" metric as:

> Item revenue = price x quantity
>
> - **Price** is the price parameter for an item in the items array
> - **Quantity** is the quantity parameter for an item in the items array

Ultimately, it depends on how you would like to define & calculate "Item Revenue" within in your Google Analytics Reports, but with revenue meaning, "the total amount of money a business earns from the sale of goods or services", and not the total retail/MSRP value of the items purchased, then it would make sense then to use the example provided by [Apply a discount to an ecommerce event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/apply-discount?hl=en&client_type=gtm) that shows that the "Item Revenue" &  `ecommerce.value` would be calculated as the sum of the ecommerce.items[] `price * quantity` and **NOT** `(price - discount) * quantity`.

Answer (score 0):

The most common usage, as shown in the ga4 docs code examples you referenced, loops over the item array where the sum of all {item.price (gross) minus item.discount} equals the event (net) 'value'.

example: "event", "some_ec_event", { value: 19.85, items [ { price: 11, discount: 1 }, { price: 14, discount: 4.15 }, ... ], ...

That said, it is user's choice as to what your numbers mean and there can be valid accounting/reporting reasons to use discount some other way. One way or another is not necessarily the "correct" way to do something. The important thing is to clearly define what your values mean and communicate the data definitions to those who build reports and consume the numbers so that they can determine the difference between gross and net.

for more: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#purchase