# What value to mention in the price property of items in Google ecommerce events?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

So I am trying to send ga ecommerce events such as "add_to_cart" or "begin_checkout". Now, in the event objects, I am confused as to what price to mention in the items array of the event object. Do I mention the discounted price or the full price?

Allow me to elaborate with examples.

```
gtag("event", "purchase", {
    transaction_id: "T_12345",
    coupon: "socksSale",
    value: 12.00, // value = quantity x sale price
    currency: "USD", // The currency of the value, discount, and price
    items: [
     {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: "Socks",
      discount: 2.00, // The discount per item
      price: 4.00, // The sale price is the per item list price (6.00) minus discount (2.00)
      quantity: 3 // The number of items sold
    },
    ]
});
```

This example is taken directly from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/apply-discount?client_type=gtag

Now, in the above example, Google states that the price of the items must be the **discounted price**:

> The sale price is the per item list price (6.00) minus discount (2.00)

Now, consider another example. (Again from Google)

```
gtag("event", "add_to_cart", {
  currency: "USD",
  value: 7.77,
  items: [
    {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
      affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
      coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
      discount: 2.22,
      index: 0,
      item_brand: "Google",
      item_category: "Apparel",
      item_category2: "Adult",
      item_category3: "Shirts",
      item_category4: "Crew",
      item_category5: "Short sleeve",
      item_list_id: "related_products",
      item_list_name: "Related Products",
      item_variant: "green",
      location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
      price: 9.99,
      quantity: 1
    }
    ]
});
```

This example is taken directly from here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#add_to_cart

Here, the item price is clearly not the discounted price as the event value is this price minus the item discount e.g. The **full price**.

The above examples show a clear contradiction in the guidelines.

I was able to find one relevant question on Stack Overflow here: [What Discount property means in Google Analytics 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66426658/what-discount-property-means-in-google-analytics-4) . The only answer here states that item prices should be the **full prices**.

Now, I understand that one can send either of the 2 types of prices as they are the ones who have to interpret the reports afterwards. However, I am sending the data to Google Ads from Google Analytics as well. And, I do not want to report inaccurate data. So, what is the more standard/accepted method of reporting item prices?